# Recaptcha V3 error incorrect-captcha-sol randomly

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I'm getting `incorrect-captcha-sol` error code sometime while using Google reCAPTCHA server side verification api.

I have integrated google recaptcha validation to some of my apis.

To do so, I pass recaptcha token on these api requests from client side and then verify it on server side by following [server side validation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) of recaptcha.

I am getting recaptcha token by executing below code and pass this token to my api request header:

```js
const getRecaptchaToken = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      if (window.grecaptcha && typeof window.grecaptcha.execute === "function") {
        grecaptchaExecute(window.grecaptcha.execute);
      } else {
        window.grecaptcha.ready(async () => {
          grecaptchaExecute(window.grecaptcha.execute);
        });
      }

      // grecaptcha execute action
      async function grecaptchaExecute(ExecuteAction) {
        const captchaToken = await ExecuteAction(
          xxxxxx, // my recaptcha site key
          {
            action: "submit",
          }
        );
        return resolve(captchaToken);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return reject(error);
    }
  });
};
```

Then, on server side I call:

```js
`https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${secret_key}&response=${captchaToken}`;
```

Most of time it is working fine, but some of calls randomly fail and return `incorrect-captcha-sol` error code.

Since it's happening randomly, I don't have a good idea when it is occurring and why.  Also, I can't find the any details about this error code in the recaptcha documentations.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue but I got this error when I was using a website that did not have HTTPS.

Comment: same issue here. I am using HTTPS and still getting it from time to time (less than 1% of requests).

Comment: I have the same problem, I read all related topics but didn't find any solution I also couldn't re generate the exception to find out what can we do in these cases. maybe getting a new token from google or something else. did you find any solution for that ?

Comment: You are probably not passing in the user's input into the verification routine because you're not getting them from the previous step.

Comment: @AbdelrhmanArnos what do you mean by "user's input"? Recaptcha v3 has no user input.

Comment: This [link](https://2captcha.com/blog/google-doesnt-accept-recaptcha-answers) provides  info about multiple ways you can get the error. So if you are doing testing several times a day then you might get the error cos their analytics might think you are a bot. Repasting the link so that people who can not see deleted answers get the info.

Comment: [verifyCaptcha] {  "success": false,  "error-codes": [    "incorrect-captcha-sol"  ]}

i have experience when handle it, its because whitelist url.

Comment: Not familiar with this code. But try including `fast: true` with `action: 'submit'`. When adding this option, you'll probably need to change cookies limit.

Answer (score 0):

If it happens randomly and most of time it works fine you can use`try` function so if it receives an `incorrect-captcha-sol` it will repeat until the code will work normally. Here is the code:

```
try {
   function Captcha(){
      const getRecaptchaToken = () => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
      if (window.grecaptcha && typeof window.grecaptcha.execute === "function") {
        grecaptchaExecute(window.grecaptcha.execute);
      } else {
        window.grecaptcha.ready(async () => {
          grecaptchaExecute(window.grecaptcha.execute);
        });
      }
      // grecaptcha execute action
      async function grecaptchaExecute(ExecuteAction) {
        const captchaToken = await ExecuteAction(
          APIKEY, 
          {
            action: "submit",
          }
        );
        return resolve(captchaToken);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return reject(error);
    }
  });
};
    }
 } catch (error) {

  Captcha();
 }
```